# Add Feed to Case Lightning Record Page

Tags: lightning, case, chatter-feed

I mistakenly deleted the Feed From my Case lightning Record Page.
What component do I need to use to restore this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Standard Lightning Page Components](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_components.htm&type=5) lists and describes what each does. There's a couple that cover the area you're looking at, but it's not clear if there's a feed below that component on the screenshot.

1. **Chatter Feed** Component - displays the feed of the record
2. **Chatter Publisher** Component - what you have (*that we can see*) in your screenshot, ability to take actions on the feed (post, tasks, email, etc).
3. **Chatter** Component - all in one combo of #1 & #2

[image]

If all else fails, you can just drag all the components in the Lightning App Builder and see that the preview looks as you documented previously.

Comment: Why would I not be seeing the chatter components?
https://www.screencast.com/t/8WIekiAI1f

Comment: You have to have [Feed Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321124&type=1&mode=1) enabled on the object. `Setup --> Feed Tracking --> Case --> Enable Feed Tracking`

Comment: That was it - Feed Tracking was disabled by another Admin!

Comment: It shouldn't be. The component does not impact the value of that setting (it works the other way around, the setting impacts the availability of the component). If you're in a shared sandbox or have other admins, I'd check someone didn't set it to false by accident with a deployment of the Case object from an org that didn't have it enabled.

Comment: Kris - it was disabled early morning by another Admin.  Thanks for your support!